# Как убрать collation SQL?

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql, mysql

Как в `PHPMYADMIN` убрать из поля `varchar/text` столбик `collation`, потому что когда он есть, у меня добавляются нулевые значения в строке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы нулевые значения были невозможны, Вам нужно NOT NULL на колонку, а Collation отвечает за сортировку строк.